# typeerror in sqlalchemy

Tags: database, flask, sqlalchemy

I am unable to create a database as every time from app import db it states cannot import name db from app.And if I do some changes it shows TypeError: Additional arguments should be named _, got 'deafult'. What should i try other than sqlalchemy as there is an import error as well for pylint.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime



app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy()


class ToDo(db.Model):
      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      content = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
      date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, deafult=datetime.utcnow)

def __rep__(self):
            return'<Task %r>' % self.id
@app.route("/")
def index():
      return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run()
```

Comment: Please show the lines that don't run (it looks like you pulled them out of here) as well as the full text of the error messages.

Comment: This is the full text error:_

Comment: TypeError 
<ipython-input-1-7fdb514ef19b> in <module>
---> 13 class ToDo(db.Model):
     14       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     15       content = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
<ipython-input-1-7fdb514ef19b> in ToDo()
     14       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     15       content = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
---> 16       date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, deafult=datetime.utcnow)
     18 def __rep__(self):

Comment: ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1382             self.info = kwargs.pop("info")
-> 1384         self._extra_kwargs(**kwargs)
   1386     def _extra_kwargs(self, **kwargs):

Comment: ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py in _extra_kwargs(self, **kwargs)
   1386     def _extra_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
-> 1387         self._validate_dialect_kwargs(kwargs)
   1389     #    @property

Comment: ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py in _validate_dialect_kwargs(self, kwargs)
    287                 raise TypeError(
    288                     "Additional arguments should be "
--> 289                     "named <dialectname>_<argument>, got '%s'" % k )
    291             dialect_name, arg_name = m.group(1, 2)
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'deafult'

Comment: Not sure here but I think you should look at creating an engine and connecting to SQLite through that engine. These items appear here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html and here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlite

Comment: Thanks, I do create an engine for this and the problem is solved.

Comment: Congrats! Best of luck with your application!